# Excel Macro find last column used, insert new column and copy formulas from previous

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an "Insert Column" macro in Excel.

The workbook uses formulas and conditional formatting to display progress along a timeline.  I need to provide users with a way to add additional columns to the timeline.

The macro I am trying to build locates the last column and copies the entirety of column lastColumn into column newColumn.  However, everything that I find online and try to adapt either gives me an object error or doesn't do anything.  Please help me figure out how to do this.

Here's my code so far.

```
Sub InsertColumn()

    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim newColumn As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastColumn = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).column
    End With

    newColumn = lastColumn + 1

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Columns(lastColumn & ":" & newColumn), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: I have worked with this and (I believe) made some progress, but I still cannot get the copy-paste to work correctly.  My updated code has been posted as an edit.  Please help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply trying to copy the one column to another then this will work:

```
Sub InsertColumn()
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    Columns(lastColumn).Copy Destination:=Columns(lastColumn + 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: So adding the InsertColumn macro made me realize that I need additional help with my macro for InsertRow.

Comment: Do you want to open up a new question for your `InsertRow1 question? Or can you adapt the code for `InsertColumn` to meet your need?

Comment: Sorry about that; I started to type up a comment on Friday, then got pulled into a meeting and never got back to it.  The comment was not supposed to post.  I'm going to start a new thread, to avoid confusion.  Thank you!